# Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 Freezes My Laptop After Fifteen Minutes of Use

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I will have about five tabs open and it is fast. However, after about fifteen minutes to thirty, my Chrome will completely freeze my laptop and I'll have to hold the power button to shut-down and restart my computer.

Both Chromium and Google Chrome do this, but Firefox (my preferred browser) doesn't do this at all. Why use Chrome, then? I use Google Chrome mainly for it's stability in certain webpages I use. So is there a way to fix this freezing?

Comment: Do you have CPU usage spikes? Does `chromium` start swapping too much? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 4 Gigs of RAM, an optical drive and one solid state. So shouldn't be a memory problem. What do you mean by spikes?